# How do you use Chrome Developer Tools to find out what the cause of white space is on a web page?

Tags: html, css

Please refer to the pic, there is a bit of white space on the right side, causing a side scroll on mobile. I want to get rid of the white space, but I can't find what is causing this extra white space.

[image: White space on the right side]

Is there a way to determine what the cause of white space is (for eg due to margin or padding css error) when using Chrome Developer Tools.

Can the Chrome Inspection Developer tool get a highlight of where the white space is being caused?

Comment: Right click on the space and select inspect. It selects the top most element at this position

Comment: ctrl + shift + c should trigger the in-page element highlighter, but it may very well be an element outside of the viewport, so you may have to scroll through your page to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I previously have this problem and the error are because I accidentally misplaced a  closing tag. You should try checking your code if there is any tag that you misplaced.